# What is the purpose of creating collection classes in PHP?

Tags: php, collections

I've been reading Alejandro Gervasio's excellent Service Layers series here: http://www.devshed.com/cp/bio/Alejandro-Gervasio/ and I noticed he is also one of the developers who favors PHP Collections, as in http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/PHP-Service-Layers-Handling-Entity-Collections/1/

Why is that? Why create a class that simulates a simple associative array by using arrays in itself?

Comment: I was reading a book on advanced php oop techniques once, and it talked at length about this. Apparently they do this because it allows you to use an object itself like an array..

Comment: You can abbreviate "php oop" as "poop", fyi.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I didnt read the article but i can tell you why i do it generally speaking:

1. Searching/Sorting/Accessing: I can abstract searching, filtering, and accessing the items i want in the collection without going to the db with special methods and without being dependent on a single array key.
2. Its easier to plugin to an entity management interface if you can pass in and Entity or an EntityCollection interface - again here you can have functionality encapsulated in the collection for performing operations on multiple entities. Not that you cant just do this in a loop, but it lets you hide it away and make specific things happen for different collection classes).
3. Collection serialization - custom serialization (think picking specific attributes) for serialization to a specific string format.
4. You can still support an array interface for basic access and iteration easily.

Comment: Regarding point 1 - wouldn't a well composed dynamic query take care of the sorting and searching? Also, I usually write helper functions in a utility class for 2D sorting by property or element, which can then be called from anywhere. I mean I see how you could abstract this into the collection class, it just seems like overhead to me from my point of view. Could you name examples for points 2 and 3, please?

Answer (score 1):

If I may complete the answer with what I have observed in Doctrine 2:

With Doctrine, you use the `Collection` interface and you don't care how it works. The interface provides methods for filtering, sorting, ...

But Doctrine provides an implementation of the `Collection` named `PersistentCollection`. You don't even know you're using it because you use the interface, but with this special collection, Doctrine will be able to intelligently and transparently make database queries when you filter/search/sort the collection. It will also enable Doctrine to load the content of the collection (the list of objects) only when they are accessed (lazy-loading), which can help gain in performances.

This wouldn't be possible with a PHP array, you would have to load it entirely from the database and then perform your operations.